# Advanced Filter Criteria in Access

Tags: ms-access, filtering

The issue is simple but I just cant figure it out.

I have two tables in access, one with records and another with "key words". I need to filter the records containing certain "key words". In other words, use one table field as a filter criteria for the other, but without linking them because the "key words" table just contains random words instead of a whole record.

In excel I can run an advanced filter on my records and just specify as criteria the list of key words (and using wildcards), but in acces I havent found a way to filter according to another table fields.

Any ideas about it?

Comment: You should do some tries, and it's not matter of one single step.

Comment: Do you have a more detailed explanation of the user interface?  Do you want multiple "Key word" searches?  Are you looking to save your filters?

Comment: Yes, i do want multiple keyword searches, actually I have a list with a few hundred,  the idea is to filter them because I am positive that the records that contain those keywords are just trash. I also have a list for the keywords that indicate real data.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create a function that spits out custom SQL with all the keywords in it.  Here is an example to get you started.

```
Public Function fGetTrashRecords()
'add your own error handling
Dim SQL As String
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim rstTrash As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As DAO.Database

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT sKeyWord FROM tblBadKeyWords", dbOpenSnapshot)
If Not rst Is Nothing Then
    rst.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rst.EOF
        SQL = SQL & " strFieldContaingKeyWord LIKE *'" & rst!sKeyWord & "'* OR"
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
    If SQL > "" Then SQL = Left(SQL, Len(SQL) - 2) 'get rid of the last OR
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
End If
If SQL > "" Then
    Set rstTrash = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblHasKeyWords WHERE " & SQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    If Not rstTrash Is Nothing Then
        rstTrash.MoveFirst
        Do While Not rstTrash.EOF
            Debug.Print rstTrash!ID
            rstTrash.MoveNext
        Loop
        rstTrash.Close
        Set rstTrash = Nothing
    End If
End If
Set db = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Kind of what I do in excel, guess it is going that way then.

Thanks for the help, iys going to really help me not to beggin from scratch.

Comment: Color me purple, but shouldn't you be using the **OR** operator, and not the **AND** operator?

Comment: absolutely.  I changed the answer.